# How to came know that some web services is present in project in java

Tags: java, web-services

I don't know much about the J2EE/Web Project in Java.

Actually the thing is like that I have git some projects (10-12) inter-related with each other (contains lots of packages, classes, etc). And it requires JBOSS server to run the complete project.

I am confused after seeing some little bit code of it. When I tried to run it using JBOSS server then it opens a link in the browser.

I want to know that actually where the web service is present in the project so that I can come to know the little bit by bit things.

Sorry for asking idiot question. 
Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could search for `*.wsdl`.

Comment: I think Bhavesh might be confusing web services with web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bhavesh.. Firstly you should know which type of webservice has been developed in your project. Either REST or SOAP service.

Second thing you should know that on which library or technologies your web service built on.

for example REST based service can be developed by using Jersey or Spring MVC (in this case you can find some annotation like @RequestMappling or @GET).

SOAP based web-services commonly contain WSDL file and some .XSD (in case of contract first webservice) file.

Being without specific information it is pretty hard to tell about where is your web-service part in project.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the web.xml file of the Project.
It will give you a head start.

Comment: Juniad: I saw the web.xml file. But as I said that I have multiple projects with me, hence I saw many web.xml in some of the projects. How can I come to know that which one is playing key role among them?